# Debugging always fails in protractor in intellij ide

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am new to Protractor and trying to debug already written code.I tried debugging code but its showing this error.

```
Debugger listening on [::]:51063
Running "protractor:chrome" (protractor) task
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::51063
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
    at Agent.Server._listen2 (net.js:1259:14)
    at listen (net.js:1295:10)
    at net.js:1405:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

and also i tried to kill the process, but still its not working.

can some one please help me